# PHPExcel - dynamically check columns in a row

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel, symfony-3.4

I have a xlsx file where the first row has:

image : [image]

I need to dynamically check how much locales are there (by column name), as it can happen that it can be only one or 5/6 columns.

How to set it?

```
$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($filePath);
$activeSheet = $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('B1:G1');


dump($activeSheet);die;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first, you can use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for loading Excel files.

there is example code for counting first row keys :

```
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\xlsx();

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filePath);
    $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

    $firstRow = $sheetData[0];

    $cnt = 0;

    foreach ($firstRow as $value) {
        if($value)
            $cnt++;
    }
    //because of first column
    $cnt--;
```

the last line, mines one is because of your first column "key"

Comment: Thank you for replay. This part works but I need to retrive just first row columns where the data is, not to count empty ones. @BehzadGhanadi

Comment: I edited my code, now I checked every column of the first row

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you. @BehzadGhanadi

Comment: And if it's not too much trouble... How can I get array values of each of counted cells? @BehzadGhanadi